# How to update laravel 5.2 user edit form by using patch method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I am following laravel tutorial by jeffrey. But I have got a problem with while update the form. I'm getting all form fields but when updating it is showing that page not found. I have tried many multiple what jeffrey told how to updating form in 5.2

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

```
<form action="form/{{$user->id}}" method="POST">
{{method_field("PATCH")}}
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$user->name}}">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}">

        <label for=""></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>

this is routes
Route::get("form/{id}/edit", "you@edit");
Route::patch("form/{user}", "you@update");

This is my controller 

public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = laravel::findorfail($id);
        return view("form", compact("user"));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $user->update($request->all());
    }

Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: If you are currently on `/form` and you are trying to submit the form to `/form/{id}`, i think your action should be `/form/{{$user->id}}`.  Otherwise it's actually submitting to `/form/form/{id}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `php artisan route:clear`.

You also need to add field with CSRF token. Here's an example from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: What is `you` in `you@update`? It should be controller name there. Do you see that route in list if you run `php artisan route:list`? If you don't see it there, try to run `php artisan route:clear` and then `php artisan route:list` again.

Comment: you is my controller name only. for simple i named as you

Answer (score 1):

As I see this, the problem with the route to be `form/form/{id}` is because of your action route of the form. To avoid this add `/` before the path, then, the final path will be `/form/{id}`. Another way you can get this is just using deleting the `form/` words from you path and just keeping the `{id}`.

Explaining a little about what this is happening when you add `/` and the beginning of a route you are creating an absolute path, but if you start the path without the `/` then you are using relative path, this means that the path will depend on the current app url.

The best way to avoid this sort of things is using named routes. I always try to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out the solution.

The routes patch should be:

```
Route::patch("form/{user}", "you@update");
```

but actually it should be like:

```
Route::patch("form/form/{id}", "you@update");
```

and the update controller should be like:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = laravel::find($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return "sucess";
}
```